# Can I make a second startup USB by simply coping the contents of existing one?

Tags: installation, live-usb

I'm trying to setup a bootable firewire device. For some reason the startup disk creator keeps crashing. I already have a bootable USB. Can I just copy and paste the files from the USB to the firewire device? Or is there something else that the startup disk creator does?

Comment: Have you tried with Unetbootin instead?.

Comment: I did get startup disk creator to create the bootable firewire device, but I'd still like to know the answer to this just to satisfy my own curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

#### First option

you'll have to use the `dd` command. try this : `dd if=/dev/your_source of=/dev/your_destination` replace your_source and your_destination with a meaningful device name, for example if your source usb device is `/dev/sdc` and your destination device is `/dev/sdd` then write `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/dev/sdd`

> be careful with dd. use this command with proper caution. don't use it unless you properly identify the disks.

#### second option

format the drive in fat32 and copy all the files from one device to another and then use syslinux to make it bootable.

type `syslinux -s /dev/your_destination_device_with_partition_number`

this time you'll need to provide the partition number(the first one in most case)

if your device is `/dev/sdc` then the first partition is `/dev/sdc1` so, run :

```
    syslinux -s /dev/sdc1
```

Comment: What’s the `-s` option for? In the man page it is said to install a _safe, slow and stupid_ version!

Comment: the `-s` option works in most of the cases. while `-i` fails in many.